# First order separable differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{xdx} = 0$$

Using change of variable equals to $Z=\frac{dy}{dx}$ what is the 1st order separable differential equation for $Z$ as function of $x$?

and solve for $y(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! People here are willing to help you but, please, show your efforts. Explain what you already tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=\frac{dy}{dx}$. Then $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{xdx} = 0$ can be written as $$\frac{dZ}{dx}+2\frac{Z}{x}=0.$$
Then $\frac{dZ}{Z}=-2\frac{dx}{x}$.  $$\int\frac{dZ}{Z}=-\int2\frac{dx}{x}$$
So it's easy to get $Z=\frac{C}{x^2}$, where $C$ is a constant. Then for  $Z=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{C}{x^2}$. We get the solution is $y=-\frac{C}{x}+C_0$, where $C_0$ is a constant.

Comment: Actually 2Z/x, not 2Z.

Comment: So does that mean that Z=x*e^(-2) +Constant ??

Comment: Sorry. I reedit it.

Comment: sorry but isnt ∫dZ/Z=−∫2dx/x equal to ln(Z)=-2ln(x)+c 
then Z=x*e^(-2)+c

and then y(x)=(x^2)/2*e^(-2) +C1x +C2

Comment: Yes. $\ln(Z)=-2\ln(x)+c$. But then we get $\ln(Z)=\ln\frac{e^c}{x^2}$. You made a mistake.

Comment: "But then we get ln(Z)=lnecx2. You made a mistake" THIS step i do not understand, It must seem silly to you sorry sleep deprivation isn't doing much for me

Comment: So you have got $\ln(Z)=-2\ln(x)+c$, then we get $ln(Z)=\ln(\frac{1}{x^2})+c$.Finally, we get $ln(Z)=\ln(\frac{e^c}{x^2})$. This is simply     the logarithm calculation.